# Javascript handling fractions in variables

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and was trying to write a simple program to find the slope of a line, and I was wondering how I could handle variables with fractions in them. Currently, if I assign any of the variables as a fraction I will get an error.

```
var oneX = prompt ("what is the X of the first coordinate?");
var oneY = prompt ("what is the Y of the first coordinate?");
var twoX = prompt ("what is the X of the second coordinate?");
var twoY = prompt ("what is the Y of the second coordinate?");

console.log(oneX);
console.log(oneY);
console.log(twoX);
console.log(twoY);

var yRes = twoY-oneY;
var xRes = twoX-oneX;

console.log(yRes);
console.log(xRes);

var slope = yRes/xRes

console.log(slope);
```

If you have any advice for making this program neater too, I'd be happy for it. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you provide an example for which you get the error? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: There’s no fraction here. You’re just dividing strings.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: The subtraction will have coerced those values to numbers (not that this is any better, but still...)

Comment: @FelixKling good spot. I didn’t see that

Comment: When you say "fraction", how are you entering those?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are right, prompt seems to be making the program treat it as a string. I'm more familiar with C# than javascript and am not sure how to get the program to treat these as integer values

Comment: Maybe youve entered `1,2` or sth like that?

Comment: @treesniper they will be always strings. To convert them to an integer ( which obviously hasnt a fraction) you can use `parseInt( prompt(...))` , if you want it as float ( two fractional digits e.g. `1.23` ) use `parseFloat` or if you want it as a js number ( even hex accepted ): `+prompt()` or `Number(prompt())`, however as you subtract them, this happens automatically

Comment: @Jonasw OP specifically says he has an issue with fractions. Neither parseInt or parseFloat will handle inputs like '1/2'

Comment: @bricky right, then store `1/2` as an integer ;)

Comment: @Jonasw You're imposing restrictions of expectable behavior onto the user.  And 0.5 is also not an integer.

Comment: @bricky *And 0.5 is also not an integer* , ok good. Now read the OPs comment again

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, this is my first post here and I didn't really provide enough info for you all, but I've got enough feedback that I've fixed my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use eval! Unless you know what eval is, why you should and shouldnt use it.

If you simply want to allow fractions then you should allow for parsing it. For instance you could simple write your code as such:

```
/*
* Tries to parse a users input, returns {@param input} as a number or
* attempts to parse the input as a fraction.
* @return Number or NaN if an invalid number or unparseable
*/
function parseUserInput(input) {
    var res = +input;
    if(isNaN(res)) {
        // try parsing as fraction
        var strval = String(input);
        var ix = strval.indexOf('/');
        if(ix !== -1) {
            try {
                res = strval.substring(0, ix) / strval.substring(ix+1);
            } catch(e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return isFinite(res) ? res : NaN;
}

var oneX = parseUserInput(prompt ("what is the X of the first coordinate?"));
var oneY = parseUserInput(prompt ("what is the Y of the first coordinate?"));
var twoX = parseUserInput(prompt ("what is the X of the second coordinate?"));
var twoY = parseUserInput(prompt ("what is the Y of the second coordinate?"));
```

---

Or a very pretty way of writing it using @Jonasw's suggestion.

```
/*
* Tries to parse a users input, returns {@param input} as a number or
* attempts to parse the input as a fraction.
* @return Number or NaN if an invalid number or unparseable
*/
function parseUserInput(input) {
  return +input.split("/").reduce((a,b)=> a/(+b||1));
}
```

Comment: Nice one ;) , `const parseUserInput = input => +input.split("/").reduce((a,b)=> a/b)` would be an alternative...

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly how I need it to! I read through the function and I'm pretty sure that I understand most of what it's doing. I'm not sure how '.reduce' works or what the '?' is doing, but I can find that out somewhere else.

Comment: @treesniper see `Array.prototype.reduce` and `ternary operator`

Comment: @ug_ i felt free to remove all the unneccessary checks ;) http://jsbin.com/gezatutote/edit?js

Comment: @Jonasw I tried that but the problem i had was it would still return `Infinity` instead of NaN for inputs like `"5/"`, which arguably doesnt matter, it just goes against the original method return value i wrote for it