# Javascript. How to convert 2.5/3 to say 3/2

Tags: javascript

```
var oneX = eval(prompt ("What's the x variable of the first set of points"));
var oneY = eval(prompt ("What's the y variable of the first set of points"));
var twoX = eval(prompt ("What's the x variable of the second set of points"));
var twoY = eval(prompt ("What's the y variable of the second set of points"));

console.log(oneX);
console.log(oneY);
console.log(twoX);
console.log(twoY);

var yRes = twoY-oneY;
var xRes = twoX-oneX;

console.log(yRes);
console.log(xRes);
var slope = xRes/yRes;

console.log("The slope is " + yRes + "/" + xRes);
```

This is my code. This is what the output looks like:

```
0.9166666666666666
0.8
2.09375
0.5714285714285714
-0.22857142857142865
1.1770833333333335
The slope is -0.22857142857142865/1.1770833333333335
```

However, I don't want -.22/1.177 I want -33/7 (I don't know the exact answer) I've never posted on StackOverflow before, so if I did something stupid while typing, I apologize. I'm new to programming so don't be too harsh.

Comment: You would need some kind of library to do that, there's nothing built in to handle that. Maybe: http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/fractions.html

Comment: Nobody on SO is ever harsh. Sometimes people are brutally honest, but that's the internet for you :)

Comment: Maybe add `2/3` ??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Exress the slope in integers only? How did you go from -.22/1.177 to -33/7 mathematically?

Comment: Can you define what -33/7 is and how you get to that? Do you mean you want to get only integer valued for your fraction? How accurate do you need it to be?

Comment: Here is the algorithm: https://www.mathsisfun.com/converting-decimals-fractions.html  (5 seconds searching the web)

Comment: You should know that there are numbers that are impossible to express as fractions. There was an ancient greek religion whose members call themselves Pythagoreans who did not want to believe that there are such numbers but they stumbled upon Pi (one of the earliest such numbers). The square root of 2 is another example of such a number. So it is not always possible to do what you want.

Comment: @miroxlav this still requires a neuronal network ;)

Comment: If your user enters rational numbers, precision will be lost when converting to floating point and doing your arithmetic (see `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`).  Perhaps searching for a fraction or rational-number library is what you need?  Also, don't use `eval`, or users can perform javascript injection attacks and mess with your code.

Comment: Same person or a homework question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46595506/218196

Comment: `convert 2.5/3 to say 3/2` ... why would you multiply by 9/5? what is the significance of 9/5?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be rounding to a certain fraction, e.g:

```
Math.round( slope * 10 ) + "/10"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is simplifying a ratio. First you multiply each number by the least common multiple to get them both into whole numbers, then divide each number by the greatest common factor to reduce them.

A full explanation of the process with examples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ratios_and_unit_rates/simplifying_ratio_decimals.htm